# VirtualBox Downloads Being Blocked With Security Warning

Tags: virtualbox, security, download

I tried to download VirtualBox from its offical site (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/downloads), however the download links for 6.0.6 and 5.2 builds are both blocked with security warnings when clicking on them.

Firefox displays: "Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead";

Bitdefender also displays: "The certificate used to encrypt your connection to this website does not match the domain it was issued for. Attackers might try to steal sensitive information from you..." (I attached both warnings as below:)

[image]

[image]

I downloaded virtualBox before, never seen these warnings previously.

Firefox's warning does not even give me a "go ahead anyway" option. Does this mean that the download links are compromised and I should not download VirtualBox?

Comment: The link is working fine for me, not sure how it's throwing that error.

Comment: @dsstorefile1 Same here, I can't go any further than this. I tried both download links for 6.0 and the earlier 5.2 builds. Either works. I'm stuck.

Comment: @CaldeiraG Did you try clicking on the "Windows Hosts" under "VirtualBox 6.0.6 platform packages"? Does it work for you? That's where I am stuck on. : -/

Comment: @RT2709 ohh, I see, i'm getting the same thing as you. But doesn't changing the link to HTTP fix your problem? it seems a certificate problem from Oracle.

Comment: @CaldeiraG I agree. I also tried on Edge, same outcome. It's not just Firefox, but a certificate issue. & Yes, changing the link to http solved the problem.

Comment: @RT2709 it really is. That will take some time to get fixed.

Comment: @Ramhound no it means there is a configuration problem at oracle that makes the https link not work at all, not even if you use the "I trust the site, continue anyway"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the same thing too when I tried to download a previous version.

If you remove the s from https:// it will work. Its not the best solution, but the actual solution is that Oracle solves the certificate problem on their end. Until then, you can download the files by clicking on the link, get the error, remove the s and press enter.

Comment: Best workaround for resolving this issue.

Comment: @Ramhound no. This weekend, I wanted to download 5.2 myself and ran into the exact same problem and my setup is configured properly and received only the standard notice of my browser.

Comment: Just a headsup: It seems that Oracle fixed this problem a moment ago, I tried the download links just now, they all work now.